# How to save a file in php, to output filename in greek

Tags: php

In PHP I want to output a file to a directory, but the filename contains Greek characters and hence the output is garbled.

```
$imagename = $ti[$img_index].'.jpg';
$filepathname = $dirpath ."/".$imagename;
$savefile = fopen($filepathname, 'w');
```

I tried doing the below but to no success:

`$filepathname = mb_convert_encoding($filepathname, 'utf8', 'iso-8859-1');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to translit the file name to the ascii charset or some different supperted by OS

```
<?php
$imagename = $ti[$img_index].'.jpg'; 
$imagename = @iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",$imagename);
$filepathname = $dirpath ."/".$imagename; 
$savefile = fopen($filepathname, 'w');
?>
```

Comment: A downside to this approach is that you might lose significant or all your characters if PHP can't find a suitable translation.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on special characters in file name. You should change your application logic (build image names randomly or based on other data, convert characters to ascii - for example cyrillic have corresponding ASCII character for each chacater od character pair, maybe this situation is similar in Greek etc.). I don't see any profits in special characters in url.

Remeber that image should be referenced by URL, so this needs additional work with urlencoding.

Think about possible problems with any migration (server, OS, configuration etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems have problems with non-ascii characters, the encoding doesn't matter.

You can encode the filename to only contain characters in the safe range. An encoding scheme that I use is [Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). It can support characters of any encoding (even UTF-16 and UTF-32) because it's a binary encoding.

If you offer the file for download you will have to undo the encoding of course.